# How to display all textbox in datagridviewTextBox of datagridview using C#application

Tags: c#

I have a problem about display control in datagridview using C#.
my datagridview have 3 column(A(combobox), B(textbox), C(textbox, width= 50)) and is loaded data from database.

when the form is display, all cell of column C will be displayed as textbox(have border and the width = 30).

I researched but don't found solution.
If you know about this, please help me.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit!**

I clearly misunderstood the question. To set the width of a of a column in a DataGridView within Windows Forms, do the following:

- Right click the grid
- Edit columns
- Select the column in question
- Go to the Layout section of its properties and change the Width property to the desired value

Does this help?

Comment: ... the question is C#, either WinForms or WPF. Your answer is CSS/HTML. How could this answer the question?

Comment: Eek! Thanks for point that out, Jashaszun. I was stuck in web dev mode, apparently. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: me issue is when display datagridview, all textbox of column C is showed, the normal when we edit value of any cell of column C, the textbox of cell will be showed to input new value. No I want textbox is showed on not edit mode.